# ArcGIS Raster Symbology - Break contour at 0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, symbology, dem

In ArcGIS 10, how can I break raster symbology (stretched) at a particular value (i.e. 0).  For example, I have a DEM representing both topography and bathymetry and I want a break at the 0 m contour line (shoreline) so the green colors represent positive elevation (land) and the blue colors represent values less than 0 (water depths).  Similar to what Global Mapper offers.

Answer (score 1):

A manual method is suggested: The only help file I could find on raster symbology relevant to your question is [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/representing_continuous_data_such_as_elevation/009t00000075000000/). However, the `Classify` button works the same when representing quantities as classified values as shown [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Classifying_numerical_fields_for_graduated_symbology/00s50000001r000000/) for both vector and raster numerical values. In the Classification dialog, right-click on the graph and Insert Break then enter values in the right-hand Break Values box. Click OK, and back in the Layer Properties Symbology tab adjust the colors as needed.